# How can we add the click event in calendar-wrapper using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, calendar

HTML Code :

```
<div class="calendar-wrapper">
<button id="btnPrev" type="button">Prev</button>
  <button id="btnNext" type="button">Next</button>
<div id="divCal"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var Cal = function(divId) {

//Store div id
this.divId = divId;

// Days of week, starting on Sunday
this.DaysOfWeek = [
'Sun',
'Mon',
'Tue',
'Wed',
'Thu',
'Fri',
'Sat'
];

// Months, stating on January
this.Months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 
'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ];

// Set the current month, year
var d = new Date();

this.currMonth = d.getMonth();
this.currYear = d.getFullYear();
this.currDay = d.getDate();

};

// Goes to next month
Cal.prototype.nextMonth = function() {
if ( this.currMonth == 11 ) {
 this.currMonth = 0;
 this.currYear = this.currYear + 1;
}
else {
 this.currMonth = this.currMonth + 1;
}
this.showcurr();
};
```

Further references to access full code with css :

https://codepen.io/xmark/pen/WQaXdv

It will be static calendar. I need click event to get the date and year. How it will be acheived ? thanks in advance

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) HERE at SO

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener

[codepen](https://codepen.io/mplungjan/pen/VwXzmLv)

```js
const getDate = function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches("td")) {
    const table = tgt.closest("table");
    const mmmyyyy = table.querySelector("thead td").textContent;
    const day = tgt.textContent;
    console.log(day, mmmyyyy);
    const sel = table.querySelector("tbody td.selected");
    if (sel) sel.classList.remove("selected")
    tgt.classList.add("selected");
  }
};

// On Load of the window
window.onload = function() {

  // Start calendar
  var c = new Cal("divCal");            
  c.showcurr();

  // Bind next and previous button clicks
  getId('btnNext').onclick = function() {
    c.nextMonth();
  };
  getId('btnPrev').onclick = function() {
    c.previousMonth();
  };
  document.querySelector("#divCal").addEventListener("click",getDate)
}
```

Comment: Since I am new to this javascript I used this function in script tag but it is not reflecting in the UI. How can be added or triggered this function ?

Comment: I made a few mistakes since I have to edit your pen and not a working example here. See update and forked pen:https://codepen.io/mplungjan/pen/VwXzmLv

Comment: Thanks for ur input. I used this code it is working for current month alone. if i click next month and click the date it is not working. Only current month page it is working

Comment: Please remove the `thead` from the querySelector

Comment: Yes its working. Thanks. Is it possible to add the selected date in blue color in the calendar using css or javascipt

Comment: Yes. `tgt.classList.toggle(“selected”)` where the css is `td.selected { color: blue; }` - see updated answer and codepen

Comment: only current selected date need to be blue. not the current date and all the clicked dates

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand the usecase then

Comment: as of now everything works fine. when we selected the date it will be blue. Thats crct. But if we click on multiple dates it all will be blue. But i need only current last selected date needs to be blue .(only one)

Comment: This is called feature creep. I fix one thing and then you ask for more and more. See updated script and pen for the solution

Comment: ok fine thanks for solving this problem.